# I quit. What can I do to get the raised salary when the promotion was just verbal?

Tags: salary, promotion

Let's say you had a salary raise for the past few months, but you haven't signed anything new (ie. you are still on the old contract with the old salary written in there).

Then, you hand in your notice and quit. After you quit, you receive just the salary written on the old contract without a bonus/raise.

Is it common for people not to get new contracts when getting a promotion or a paycheck raise? Can I do anything about this issue in order to get the raise part of the new salary paid by them?

Comment: I don't understand why you are getting a salary after you quit.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I assume it is the two weeks that he worked last. When you start, you get paid after a month, but you only get paid for two weeks, etc. If that makes sense

Comment: Hmm, the "do I need raises in writing" and "get raised salary after I quit" are two fairly distinct questions. If they dropped you back to an old salary after you quit that's dubious and scummy but depending on the amount it may not be worth making a fuss about.

Comment: How large of a raise we're talking about? The standard 2-3% or a big jump? I think location is important in this question as well as how big of a raise. A 2-3% would be way too small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have any proof of the raise other than by verbal communication? Emails? Draft/mock contract? A paycheck with the raised amount? If so, you can attempt to bring that point up to your employer.

> HR, Attached is an email/pay stub/scanned paper dated X indicating that I got a raise and I want my final pay to match that raise.

If you have paper proof, and they refuse then the only thing you can do is see a lawyer.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer = Ignoring the legal aspects of this question, Nothing.  The company started paying you more money for a promotion position but didn't put it in writing, and now that you quit and are no longer a long term investment for them.  Oral agreements are tough to enforce so it's very easy for them not to honor that agreement.  Easy decision.

Besides, in a couple of weeks it'll be a moot point anyways as you'll no longer be working for them.

Also, a raise for a time period less then a month is likely not enough dollars for a lawyer to consider it attractive enough to represent you.

Comment: Oral agreements might be enforceable if there is written evidence of that agreement having been made (in this case, payslips showing what salary was being paid). But since challenging it would involve lawyers, the company are gambling that it would not be worth the effort.